# Should I handle these exceptions inside the Class or outside?

Tags: java

I have two different approaches for my `Person` class, one will deal with possible exceptions before creating a `Person` object, the other will deal with them inside the `Person` class.

**Approach 1**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Person {
    String name;
    LocalDate birthDate;

    public Person(String name, LocalDate birthDate) {
        this.name = name;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    public void setBirthDate(LocalDate birthDate) {
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("\tName: ");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.print("\tBirth date (YYYY-MM-DD): ");
        String birthDate = scanner.nextLine();
        String[] info = birthDate.split("-");

        // This may thrown DateTimeException, if someone gives an invalid year, month or day.
        birthDate = LocalDate.of(Integer.parseInt(info[0]), Integer.parseInt(info[1]), Integer.parseInt(info[2]));

        Person mike = new Person(name, birthDate);
    }
}
```

---

---

**Approach 2**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Person {
    String name;
    LocalDate birthDate;

    public Person(String name, String birthDate) {
        this.name = name;
        this.setBirthDate(birthDate);
    }

    public void setBirthDate(String  birthDate) {
        String[] info = birthDate.split("-");

        // This may thrown DateTimeException, if someone gives an invalid year, month or day.
        birthDate = LocalDate.of(Integer.parseInt(info[0]), Integer.parseInt(info[1]), Integer.parseInt(info[2]));
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("\tName: ");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.print("\tBirth date (YYYY-MM-DD): ");
        String birthDate = scanner.nextLine();

        Person mike = new Person(name, birthDate);
    }
}
```

Should I expect that all `Person` clients will import `java.time.LocalDate` and create the dates themselves, or should I encapsulate this work inside `Person` and the clients will give just a `String`?

Comment: Where do these `DateTimeException` come from?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis from LocalDate

Comment: `LocalDate` is a type. It doesn't throw exceptions. No part of the code you've shown can throw any exceptions.

Comment: My bad, it's throw if date provided is wrong, a month set to 13 for example

Comment: Where would you want to catch any exceptions in the code you provided in the question? You would catch a `DateTimeException` (like `DateTimeParseException`) when the date is parsed.

Comment: `LocalDate` cannot have a month with a value of 13. The exception will be thrown when you construct the `LocalDate`. That's not in this code.

Comment: Did you define your own `LocalDate` class?

Comment: No, it's from Java 8: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html

Comment: I added more info to the question, have a look, please!

Comment: You can't deal with it within `Person`. `Person` already expects a properly constructed `LocalDate`.

Comment: And what if I change the constructor and my setter to get a `String` formatted like YYYY-MM-DD, instead of `LocalDate` and do the job inside my class. Then I would have to deal with it inside my `Person` class, right? Would this approach be better than getting `LocalDate` by argument?

Comment: _would have to deal with it inside [...]_ is correct. I wouldn't put that there though, no.

Comment: Hum ok, thanks @SotiriosDelimanolis, this was indeed my question, I was a bit confused. I updated the main question with both approaches and the "real" question. If you have time I'd appreciate if you post your comment as an answer so I can mark the question as answered, and a little explanation as why getting `LocalDate` directly as an argument is better than having the clients providing a simples `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Should I treat exceptions inside of it or wherever I call this setter? Does Java have some rules regarding that ?

If any data is invalid, it is a best practice **to throw the exception while constructing the object itself** to ensure that the object is in the correct state.

Also, if the data can be modified using the setter, then you need to do the validation and throw the exception to ensure that the object is in the correct state again.

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    LocalDate birthDate;

    public Person(String name, LocalDate birthDate) {
       //If input data is NOT valid,
       //throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid name and birthDate");
      //Now, if input data is valid, assign them to ref variables
      this.name = name;
      this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    public void setBirthDate(LocalDate birthDate) {
       //If input data is NOT valid,
       //throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid name and birthDate");
       this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: An `IllegalArgumentException` would be better suited and semantically correct for invalid input arguments (from the Javadoc: `Thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or inappropriate argument.`)

Comment: @dunni yes this can be used when the input data entered is not valid

Comment: When the user is trying to modify the date we are validating it again

Comment: Sorry, I decided to delete my comment and post my own solution. I understand why the setter also needs to validate it. I don't understand how do you define **invalid birthDate** in this context? Seems to me like the OP is asking where to handle `String` to `LocalDate` conversion exceptions.

Answer (score -1):

When having this kind of problem, you should ask yourself two question

1. What does the purpose of this class?
2. Where can I handle exception?

As for this case, this class is a model for a Person. A POJO model should assume their dependencies is correct (`LocalDate birthDate`). To assume client of this model put correct input, you can throws an Exception on its method.

```
public Person(String name, LocalDate birthDate) throws DateTimeException {
        this.name = name;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

public void setBirthDate(LocalDate birthDate) throws DateTimeException {
    this.birthDate = birthDate;
```

And now the exception handling is handled by the client of this Person class.

```
try{
    DateTimeFormatter germanFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(
            FormatStyle.MEDIUM).withLocale(Locale.GERMAN);

    LocalDate newYear = LocalDate.parse("01.01.2016", germanFormatter);
    Person person = new Person("Joe", newYear);

}catch (DateTimeException e){
    // Do something about it
}
```

Comment: why throw `DateTimeException`  when you already have a `LocalDate` ?

Comment: because the creation of LocalDate may failed. Try put "01.012015" as an input. Or any other wrong input.

Comment: What? Look at your code. How can I input a string when the parameter is `LocalDate` ?  There is no reason for the ctor to throw that kind of exception since in the ctor the birthDate is already a `LocalDate`.

Answer (score -1):

Since I don't agree with either of the answers provided I will explain how I would do it.

First, as you describe the problem it looks like user input will be a `String` which *should* represent a valid `LocalDate`.

A common pattern that applies here it's the one called **throw early, catch late**. Since the clients of your `Person` are dealing with user input, they have the first chance to throw/deal with the problem and have the most information available (e.g they can attempt to guide user in a way that he can convert his input to a valid `LocalDate`).

Why should the `Person` care about converting `String` into `LocalDate`? It should only deal with `Person` related state and behavior. They can also perform validation but these are business specific checks like not allowing a `Person` object to be constructed when his birthday is in the future (if this doesn't make sense, maybe it those). In such cases it should definitely not throw a `DateTimeException` but rather a more appropriate, user defined exception.

```
public Person(String name, LocalDate birthDate) throws InvalidBirthDateException {...}
public void setBirthDate(LocalDate birthDate) throws InvalidBirthDateException {...}
```

The above contract clearly states that the `Person` class accepts a `LocalDate` birthDate and let the clients deal with necessary data conversion, but it also states that there might be some dates which do not represent a valid birthDate for a person in which case the method will throw a custom exception that the clients can catch and attempt to fix.

My point is this: let clients deal with invalid input because they can fix it. Exceptions are designed to be handled when possible. Imagine how you handle a bad date inside `Person`. At best you return an error message and the clients still need to add user-input specific logic to catch and try to recover. Do not assume that `Person` knows where the user input comes from (it might be a command line, a GUI or it might be a file).